# PostgreSQL setting up a custom constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a an appointments table with this structure (chunked for readability):

```
appointments:
 - id
 - staff_id
 - start_time
 - end_time
 - cancelled
```

I want to add a database constraint to not be able to double book appointments. I was wondering if it was possible to add a constraint along the lines of:

`when staff_id = ? and cancelled = false then set a "unique" constraint on start_time`

If this is not possible is there something similar I can do to achieve my end goal?

## EDIT

this is the full appointments table

```
CREATE TABLE "appointments" (
            "id" uuid,
            "customer_id" uuid NOT NULL REFERENCES customers ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
            "staff_id" uuid NOT NULL REFERENCES staff ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
            "start_time" timestamp NOT NULL,
            "end_time" timestamp NOT NULL,
            "notes" text,
            "cancelled" boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
            "created_at" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
            "updated_at" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
        );
```

With the exclusion:

```
CREATE TABLE "appointments" (
        "id" uuid,
        "customer_id" uuid NOT NULL REFERENCES customers ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        "staff_id" uuid NOT NULL REFERENCES staff ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        "start_time" timestamp NOT NULL,
        "end_time" timestamp NOT NULL,
        "notes" text,
        "cancelled" boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
        "created_at" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
        "updated_at" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
        EXCLUDE USING gist (
            staff_id WITH =,
            tsrange(start_time, end_time) WITH &&
        ) WHERE (NOT cancelled),
        PRIMARY KEY ("id")
    );
```

Executing with exclusion error:

`data type uuid has no default operator class for access method "gist"`

Comment: The chosen answer doesn't work as you've requested. [See this answer for how to actually stop double booking with an exclusion constraint.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43456174/124486)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an exclusion constraint to stop the double booking of appointments. The method in the chosen answer only stops two appointments from having the same start time. It doesn't stop one appointment from overlapping if it starts after the first appointment.

```
CREATE TABLE appointments (
  id          serial PRIMARY KEY,
  staff_id    int,
  start_time  timestamp,
  end_time    timestamp,
  cancelled   bool   DEFAULT false,
  EXCLUDE USING gist (
    staff_id WITH =,
    tsrange(start_time, end_time) WITH &&
  ) WHERE (NOT cancelled)
);
```

Now you can't double book appointments.

```
INSERT INTO appointments (staff_id, start_time, end_time) VALUES
  ( 1, '01-01-2010T07:30', '01-01-2010T09:30' ),
  ( 1, '01-01-2010T08:00', '01-01-2010T09:45' )
;

ERROR:  conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "appointments_staff_id_tsrange_excl"
DETAIL:  Key (staff_id, tsrange(start_time, end_time))=(1, ["2010-01-01 08:00:00","2010-01-01 09:45:00")) conflicts with existing key (staff_id, tsrange(start_time, end_time))=(1, ["2010-01-01 07:30:00","2010-01-01 09:30:00")).
```

You can alternatively delete `start_time` and `end_time` and put them all as [timestamp-ranges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html)

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for; however, I'm getting the error `column "can" named in key does not exist` should `can` be start_time?

Comment: @Rodrigo updated it. I was fixing it to have the predicate on cancelled. I missed that originally.

Comment: Do I need any special extensions to use gist? I'm getting the error `data type text has no default operator class for access method "gist"`

Comment: @Rodrigo post the `\d appointments` above. Let's see what your table currently looks like.

Comment: @Rodrigo the problem is that `staff_id` is a text type. Ids should *never* be text. However, if you can't fix that you can use the extension [`btree_gist`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/btree-gist.html) which should solve it. You should look at making `staff_id`, `int` though.

Comment: All my ids are UUID. to avoid this should I just remove `start_time` & `end_time` and create a timestamp-ranges column?

Comment: @Rodrigo yes, well you could do that. 9.6 doesn't support gist on UUID. [Pg 10.0](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/btree-gist.html) but it's not out yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
create unique index the_index on appointments (staff_id, start_time)
where not cancelled;
```

Comment: This doesn't actually stop appointments from being double booked. [see this answer for how to stop double booking with an exclusion constraint.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43456174/124486)

Comment: @EvanCarroll The requirements are absent in the question.

Comment: *I want to add a database constraint to not be able to double book appointments.* "Double book" usually means any conflict. Not just conflicts on start time.

Comment: @EvanCarroll _usually means..._ That is just a guess, although a good one.